# html - incorrect use of inline-block?

Tags: html

I'm trying to align these 2 elements side by side rather than vertically, I thought inline block would do it but I'm obviously not using it correctly, can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 264px;
  height: 310px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.rex {
  border: 0px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 264px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rex">
  <div class="block">
    <img src="MainImg">
    <img src="ContentTypeImg">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Samples</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WEBCASTS</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
      <h4> Description </h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5> Author </h5>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br />

  <div class="block">
    <img src="MainImg">
    <img src="ContentTypeImg">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Samples</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WEBCASTS</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
      <h4> Description </h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5> Author </h5>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br />

</div>
```

Comment: remove the break..

Comment: Then why your parent "rex" and child "block" same width? I think each child element taking space full of it's parents that's why in new line also remove your <br /> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Two issues here. You had an explicit break between the two elements (`<br>`)
- The outer div (`.rex`) had the same width as the inner ones (`.block`)

So to solve

- Remove the `<br>`
- Calculate the width of `.rex` to be twice as much as the width + twice the border of one `.block`
- Set `font-size` of `.rex` to zero and that of `.block` to `1rem` to prevent whitespace between the two `.block` elements to take effect

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 264px;
  height: 310px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.rex {
  font-size: 0;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: calc(264px * 2 + 1px * 2 * 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="rex">
  <div class="block">
    <img src="MainImg">
    <img src="ContentTypeImg">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Samples</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WEBCASTS</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
      <h4> Description </h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5> Author </h5>
    </div>

  </div>
  

  <div class="block">
    <img src="MainImg">
    <img src="ContentTypeImg">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Samples</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WEBCASTS</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
      <h4> Description </h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5> Author </h5>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an *explicit line break* (`<br>`) between them.